# Blogger comment box doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: html, xml, mobile, comments, blogger

I'm having trouble with readers being able to submit comments on my blog. If they send a comment from a PC/Mac, it goes through, but if they try from a mobile device or tablet the comment box just doesn't work.

How can I fix this? I've tried everything (from different platforms, with and without Google login) but it doesn't seem to work. The template designer isn't available to fix the problem right now so I have to fix it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to add some `css` to your template inside the template HTML and then use this CSS

```
.blogger-iframe-colorize { 
display: block !important; 
}
```

> use this css just above the `]] ></b:skin>`

Comment: Hi Nischal!Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I've tried it before and it doesn't work for me. The comment box (and the rest of the footer widgets) shows up in the mobile view but it doesn't work, it freezes. That's my problem :(

Comment: Did you add the CSS in your template

Comment: Try to open it up in incognito mode

Comment: I've done it. I've tried almost everything. The comments box shows up but nobody can use it.